# Lipschitz constant of a function on a compact set

Tags: lipschitz-functions

Let $K$ be a compact set of a normed space $(X, \|\cdot\|)$. Suppose $f \colon K \to \mathbb R$ satisfies
$$
\frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{\|x-y\|} < 1
\qquad \text{for all } x, y \in K \text{ with $x \neq y$}.
$$
Then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $1$.

**Q1**: Is $f$ also Lipschitz continuous with some Lipschitz constant $L<1$?

**Q2**: Does the answer remain the same if we replace $X$ and $R$ by generic metric spaces?

Assuming $K$ to be compact is necessary: For $K = \mathbb R$  any $f \in C^1(\mathbb R)$ with $\|f'\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R)} = 1$ but $|f'| < 1$ on $\mathbb R$ (example: $f(x) = \ln(\textrm{e}^x+1)$ for $x \in \mathbb R$) is a counterexample.

A natural way to prove such a claim is to argue by contradiction and assume that there are $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb N}, (y_k)_{k \in \mathbb N} \subset K$ such that
$$
\frac{|f(x_k) - f(y_k)|}{\|x_k-y_k\|} \le 1 - \frac{1}{k}
\qquad \text{for all } k \in \mathbb N.
$$
As $K$ is compact, after switching to a subsequence we may assume that $x_k \to x$ and $y_k \to y$ as $k \to \infty$ for some $x, y \in K$. However, I fail to see how to arrive at a contradiction if $x=y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$L$ fails to exist even in very simple cases.

Let $X=\mathbb R, K=[0,1]$ and $f(x)=\sin x$. Let $x <y$. Then $|f(x)-f(y)| =|\int_x^{y} \cos t dt| \leq |x-y|$ and equality cannot hold unless $|\cos t|=1$ for all $t \in (x,y)$. But this is is not true, so  $|f(x)-f(y)| <|x-y|$.

Suppose ther exists $L <1$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| =L |x-y|$  for al $x,y$. Then $\sin x\leq L x$ for all $x$ and we get a contradiction by dividing by $x$ and letting $x \to 0$.

Comment: That is a very nice and simple counterexample. Thank you!